# pyspark: TypeError: IntegerType can not accept object in type <type 'unicode'>

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

programming with pyspark on a Spark cluster,
the data is large and in pieces so can not be loaded into the memory or check the sanity of the data easily

basically it looks like

```
af.b Current%20events 1 996
af.b Kategorie:Musiek 1 4468
af.b Spesiaal:RecentChangesLinked/Gebruikerbespreking:Freakazoid 1 5209
af.b Spesiaal:RecentChangesLinked/Sir_Arthur_Conan_Doyle 1 5214
```

wikipedia data:

I read it from aws S3 and then try to construct spark Dataframe with the following python code in pyspark intepreter:

```
parts = data.map(lambda l: l.split())
wikis = parts.map(lambda p: (p[0], p[1],p[2],p[3]))


fields = [StructField("project", StringType(), True),
StructField("title", StringType(), True),
StructField("count", IntegerType(), True),
StructField("byte_size", StringType(), True)] 

schema = StructType(fields) 

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(wikis, schema)
```

all look fine, only createDataFrame gives me error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 404, in   createDataFrame
rdd, schema = self._createFromRDD(data, schema, samplingRatio)
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 298, in _createFromRDD
_verify_type(row, schema)
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1152, in _verify_type
_verify_type(v, f.dataType)
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1136, in _verify_type
raise TypeError("%s can not accept object in type %s" % (dataType, type(obj)))
TypeError: IntegerType can not accept object in type <type 'unicode'>
```

why I can not set the third column which should be count to IntegerType ?
How can I solve this ?

Comment: could it be because your byte_size Structfield is of type StringType and should be IntegerType?

Comment: @ccheneson  thx for the comment

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As noted by [ccheneson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/143505/ccheneson) you pass wrong types.

Assuming you `data` looks like this:

```
data = sc.parallelize(["af.b Current%20events 1 996"])
```

After the first map you get `RDD[List[String]]`:

```
parts = data.map(lambda l: l.split())
parts.first()
## ['af.b', 'Current%20events', '1', '996']
```

The second map converts it to tuple `(String, String, String, String)`:

```
wikis = parts.map(lambda p: (p[0], p[1], p[2],p[3]))
wikis.first()
## ('af.b', 'Current%20events', '1', '996')
```

Your `schema` states that 3rd columns is an integer:

```
[f.dataType for f in schema.fields]
## [StringType, StringType, IntegerType, StringType]
```

Schema is used most to avoid a full table scan to infer types and doesn't perform any type casting.

You can either cast your data during last map:

```
wikis = parts.map(lambda p: (p[0], p[1], int(p[2]), p[3]))
```

Or define `count` as a `StringType` and cast column

```
fields[2] = StructField("count", StringType(), True)
schema = StructType(fields) 

wikis.toDF(schema).withColumn("cnt", col("count").cast("integer")).drop("count")
```

On a side note `count` is reserved word in SQL and shouldn't be used as a column name. In Spark it will work as expected in some contexts and fail in another.

Answer (score -1):

With apache 2.0 you can let spark infer the schema of your data. Overall you'll need to cast in your parser function as argued above:

"When schema is None, it will try to infer the schema (column names and types) from data, which should be an RDD of Row, or namedtuple, or dict."