# Unicode error while reading data from file/rdd

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I am trying to create dataframe with proper schema after fetching data from text file. in RDD, all data types are strings however one of the field data type is interger, which i want to ensure that created as integer. So i created Structtype and created dataframe. but it throws an error as below.

Error Message:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 df.show()
>
> /Users/nagaraju.n/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.pyc
>   in show(self, n, truncate, vertical)
>       376         """
>       377         if isinstance(truncate, bool) and truncate:
>   --> 378             print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
>       379         else:
>       380             print(self._jdf.showString(n, int(truncate), vertical))
>
> /Applications/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.pyc
>   in **call**(self, *args)    1284         answer =
>   self.gateway_client.send_command(command)    1285         return_value
>   = get_return_value(
>   -> 1286             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)    1287     1288         for temp_arg in temp_args:
>
> /Users/nagaraju.n/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/utils.pyc
>   in deco(*a, **kw)
>        61     def deco(*a, **kw):
>        62         try:
>   ---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
>        64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
>        65             s = e.java_exception.toString()
>
> /Applications/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py4j/protocol.pyc
>   in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
>       326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
>       327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
>   --> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
>       329             else:
>       330                 raise Py4JError(
>
> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o64.showString. :
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0
>   in stage 3.0 (TID 5, localhost, executor driver):
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File
>   "/Users/nagaraju.n/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py",
>   line 377, in main
>       process()   File "/Users/nagaraju.n/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py",
>   line 372, in process
>       serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)   File
>   "/Users/nagaraju.n/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py",
>   line 393, in dump_stream
>       vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))   File "/Users/nagaraju.n/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/util.py",
>   line 99, in wrapper
>       return f(*args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/nagaraju.n/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/session.py",
>   line 730, in prepare
>       verify_func(obj)   File "/Users/nagaraju.n/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/types.py",
>   line 1389, in verify
>       verify_value(obj)   File "/Users/nagaraju.n/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/types.py",
>   line 1370, in verify_struct
>       verifier(v)   File "/Users/nagaraju.n/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/types.py",
>   line 1389, in verify
>       verify_value(obj)   File "/Users/nagaraju.n/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/types.py",
>   line 1315, in verify_integer
>       verify_acceptable_types(obj)   File "/Users/nagaraju.n/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/types.py",
>   line 1278, in verify_acceptable_types
>       % (dataType, obj, type(obj)))) TypeError: field id: IntegerType can not accept object u'1' in type
>
> at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:452)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:588)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:571)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:406)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)   at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)    at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)    at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:255)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)   at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
>     at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>
> Driver stacktrace:    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1889)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1877)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
>     at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2110)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2059)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2048)
>     at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:737)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)    at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:365)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3383)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2544)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2544)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$53.apply(Dataset.scala:3364)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3363)  at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2544)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2758)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:254)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:291)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)  at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)    at
>   py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)     at
>   py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>     at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
>   py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File
>   "/Users/nagaraju.n/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py",
>   line 377, in main
>       process()   File "/Users/nagaraju.n/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py",
>   line 372, in process
>       serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)   File
>   "/Users/nagaraju.n/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py",
>   line 393, in dump_stream
>       vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))   File "/Users/nagaraju.n/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/util.py",
>   line 99, in wrapper
>       return f(*args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/nagaraju.n/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/session.py",
>   line 730, in prepare
>       verify_func(obj)   File "/Users/nagaraju.n/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/types.py",
>   line 1389, in verify
>       verify_value(obj)   File "/Users/nagaraju.n/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/types.py",
>   line 1370, in verify_struct
>       verifier(v)   File "/Users/nagaraju.n/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/types.py",
>   line 1389, in verify
>       verify_value(obj)   File "/Users/nagaraju.n/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/types.py",
>   line 1315, in verify_integer
>       verify_acceptable_types(obj)   File "/Users/nagaraju.n/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/types.py",
>   line 1278, in verify_acceptable_types
>       % (dataType, obj, type(obj)))) TypeError: field id: IntegerType can not accept object u'1' in type
>
> at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:452)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:588)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:571)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:406)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)   at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)    at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)    at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:255)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)   at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
>     at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     ... 1 more
>
> ```
> #!/usr/bin/env python
> ```
>
> ## coding: utf-8
>
> ## In[11]:
>
> import os import sys from pyspark import SparkContext from pyspark.sql
>   import SparkSession from pyspark.sql.types import *
>   spark=SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate() sc =
>   SparkContext.getOrCreate()
>
> ## In[12]:
>
> ## Reads data from file and creates rdd rdd=sc.textFile('/Users/nagaraju.n/Downloads/sample_data.txt')
>
> ## In[13]:
>
> type(rdd)
>
> ## In[14]:
>
> rdd_data=rdd.map(lambda p: p.split(","))
>
> ## In[15]:
>
> rdd_data.collect()
>
> ## In[16]:
>
> print(rdd_data)
>
> ## In[17]:
>
> orig_header=rdd_data.first()
>
> ## In[18]:
>
> type(orig_header)
>
> ## In[19]:
>
> rdd_withoutheader=rdd_data.filter(lambda p:p != orig_header)
>
> ## In[20]:
>
> rdd_withoutheader.collect()
>
> ## In[21]:
>
> ## Create Schema header = StructType([StructField("id", IntegerType(), True),StructField("first_name", StringType(),
>
> True),StructField("last_name", StringType(),
>   True),StructField("email", StringType(), True),StructField("phone",
>   StringType(), True),StructField("city", StringType(),
>   True),StructField("country", StringType(), True)])
>
> ## In[22]:
>
> header
>
> ## In[23]:
>
> df=spark.createDataFrame(rdd_withoutheader,header)
>
> ## In[24]:
>
> df.show()

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33129918/pyspark-typeerror-integertype-can-not-accept-object-in-type-type-unicode

Answer (score 0):

/// Part of your code:

header = StructType([StructField("stockticker", StringType(), True),StructField("tradedate", IntegerType(), True),StructField("openprice", FloatType(), True),StructField("highprice", FloatType(), True),StructField("lowprice", FloatType(), True),StructField("closeprice", FloatType(), True),StructField("volume", IntegerType(), True)])

df=spark.createDataFrame(rdd_data,header)

///

My answer:

Schema is used most to avoid a full table scan to infer types and doesn't perform any type casting. Hence above method best works for Json/avro/parquet input files not for text files. For textfiles following are the best methods:

**Method 1 based on your code, convert rdd to dataframe and define schema as below:**

rdd=sc.textFile('/Users/nagaraju.n/Downloads/sample_data.txt')

df_noType=data.map(lambda p: p.split(",")).toDF(["id", "first_name", "last_name", "email", "phone", "city", "country"])

## Now you can type cast either of these ways:

***Way1:***

df_typecast=df_noType.select(df_noType.id.cast('int'), df_noType.first_name, df_noType.last_name, df_noType.email, df_noType.phone, df_noType.city, df_noType.country)

Note: in above line no need to type cast other fields to string as they are bydefault string

Note: if decimals are there then you can use df_noType.id.cast('float')

(or)

***way2:***

from pyspark.sql.types import *

df_typecast=df_noType.select(df_noType.id.cast(IntegerType()), df_noType.first_name.cast(StringType()), df_noType.last_name.cast(StringType()), df_noType.email.cast(StringType()), df_noType.phone.cast(StringType()), df_noType.city.cast(StringType()), df_noType.country.cast(StringType()))

**Method 2: I usually use this always which I feel best and easy**

rdd=sc.textFile('/Users/nagaraju.n/Downloads/sample_data.txt')

from pyspark.sql import Row

df=rdd.map(lambda p: Row(id= int(p.split(",")[0]), first_name= p.split(",")[1], last_name=  p.split(",")[2], email= p.split(",")[3], phone= p.split(",")[4], city= p.split(",")[5], country=p.split(",")[6])).toDF()

df.printSchema()

Note: if decimals are there then you can use float(p.split(",")[0])

Comment: Thanks Sri, I got the below error when i try Method2: 

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'id'

Comment: hi you have to remove first line, from your data which is header before applying above function. Hope you got. your data first line is  ' id, first_name and so on'. since id is string its giving value error.